How to add an icon in a page title on FilamentPHP?
I am using FilamentPHP. I have a page where I override the page title, but I want to add an icon of a star next to the title based on an attribute of my model. Below is a poor man's version with just the word star, but not the icon heroicon-o-star.
    public function getTitle(): string | Htmlable
    {
        return $this->record->name . ($this->record->is_favorite ? ' (STAR)' : '');
    }


If you look closely to the function's definition, you'll be able to see that you can return an Htmlable. By doing it, you'll be able to render HTML, or even markdown:
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable;
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;

...

public function getTitle(): string | Htmlable
{
    return new HtmlString('
        <span>Example</span>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="124.13" height="128" viewBox="0 0 256 264"><path fill="#FF2D20" d="M255.856 59.62c.095.351.144.713.144 1.077v56.568c0 1.478-.79 2.843-2.073 3.578L206.45 148.18v54.18a4.135 4.135 0 0 1-2.062 3.579l-99.108 57.053c-.227.128-.474.21-.722.299c-.093.03-.18.087-.278.113a4.15 4.15 0 0 1-2.114 0c-.114-.03-.217-.093-.325-.134c-.227-.083-.464-.155-.68-.278L2.073 205.938A4.128 4.128 0 0 1 0 202.36V32.656c0-.372.052-.733.144-1.083c.031-.119.103-.227.145-.346c.077-.216.15-.438.263-.639c.077-.134.19-.242.283-.366c.119-.165.227-.335.366-.48c.119-.118.274-.206.408-.309c.15-.124.283-.258.453-.356h.005L51.613.551a4.135 4.135 0 0 1 4.125 0l49.546 28.526h.01c.165.104.305.232.454.351c.134.103.284.196.402.31c.145.149.248.32.371.484c.088.124.207.232.279.366c.118.206.185.423.268.64c.041.118.113.226.144.35c.095.351.144.714.145 1.078V138.65l41.286-23.773V60.692c0-.36.052-.727.145-1.072c.036-.124.103-.232.144-.35c.083-.217.155-.44.268-.64c.077-.134.19-.242.279-.366c.123-.165.226-.335.37-.48c.12-.118.269-.206.403-.309c.155-.124.289-.258.454-.356h.005l49.551-28.526a4.13 4.13 0 0 1 4.125 0l49.546 28.526c.175.103.309.232.464.35c.128.104.278.197.397.31c.144.15.247.32.37.485c.094.124.207.232.28.366c.118.2.185.423.267.64c.047.118.114.226.145.35m-8.115 55.258v-47.04l-17.339 9.981l-23.953 13.792v47.04l41.297-23.773zm-49.546 85.095V152.9l-23.562 13.457l-67.281 38.4v47.514zM8.259 39.796v160.177l90.833 52.294v-47.505L51.64 177.906l-.015-.01l-.02-.01c-.16-.093-.295-.227-.444-.34c-.13-.104-.279-.186-.392-.3l-.01-.015c-.134-.129-.227-.289-.34-.433c-.104-.14-.227-.258-.31-.402l-.005-.016c-.093-.154-.15-.34-.217-.515c-.067-.155-.154-.3-.196-.464v-.005c-.051-.196-.061-.403-.082-.604c-.02-.154-.062-.309-.062-.464V63.57L25.598 49.772l-17.339-9.97zM53.681 8.893L12.399 32.656l41.272 23.762L94.947 32.65L53.671 8.893zm21.468 148.298l23.948-13.786V39.796L81.76 49.778L57.805 63.569v103.608zM202.324 36.935l-41.276 23.762l41.276 23.763l41.271-23.768zm-4.13 54.676l-23.953-13.792l-17.338-9.981v47.04l23.948 13.787l17.344 9.986zm-94.977 106.006l60.543-34.564l30.264-17.272l-41.246-23.747l-47.489 27.34l-43.282 24.918z"/></svg>
    ');
}

You can see other examples on how to use it across the Filament's documentation. For example here.
Laravel API docs:

HtmlString
Htmlable

EDIT:
Seems you can do this too:
public function getTitle(): string | Htmlable
{
    $svg = svg('heroicon-o-star')->toHtml();

    return new HtmlString("
        <div class=\"flex items-center\">
            <span>hi</span>
            {$svg}
        </div>
    ");
}


Hmm. I was hoping for a solution that allowed me to use the identifier heroicon-o-star, because this might change at some time, and I would want to avoid hard-coding the SVG. If not possible, then I will use this and just centralise the SVG in a constant.

i edited the answer @nvcleemp, there is a way to use that identifier!

I wrote a PHP trait that you can reuse in your Filament page classes across the project to add an icon to the heading. You can also customize the icon's color, size, and position (before or after the heading text).
In my Filament projects I add that trait in app/Filament/Pages/Concerns directory.
file: app/Filament/Pages/Concerns/HasHeadingIcon.php
<?php
    
namespace App\Filament\Pages\Concerns;
    
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;
use Filament\Support\Enums\IconSize;
use Filament\Support\Enums\IconPosition;
    
trait HasHeadingIcon
{
    public function getHeadingWithIcon(
        ?string $heading = null,
        ?string $icon = null,
        string $iconColor = 'primary',
        IconPosition $iconPosition = IconPosition::Before,
        IconSize $iconSize = IconSize::Medium,
    ): string | Htmlable
    {
        $color = "--c-600: var(--{$iconColor}-600);";
    
        $margin = ($iconPosition === IconPosition::Before)
            ? 'margin-inline-end: .5rem;'
            : 'margin-inline-start: .5rem;';
    
        $size = match($iconSize) {
            IconSize::Small => '1.4rem',
            IconSize::Medium => '1.75rem',
            IconSize::Large => '2.5rem',
        };
    
        $dimensions = "width: {$size}; height: {$size};";
    
        $iconStyle = "{$color} {$margin} {$dimensions}";
    
        $iconComponent = filled($icon)
            ? '<x-'. $icon .' style="'. $iconStyle .'" class="inline text-custom-600" />'
            : null;
    
        $headingText = $heading ?? $this->heading ?? $this->getTitle();
    
        if (blank($iconComponent)) {
            return $headingText;
        }
    
        $iconBefore = ($iconPosition === IconPosition::Before)
            ? $iconComponent
            : null;
    
        $iconAfter = ($iconPosition === IconPosition::After)
            ? $iconComponent
            : null;

        return new HtmlString(
            Blade::render('<div class="flex items-center">
                '. $iconBefore .' '. $headingText .' '. $iconAfter .'
            </div>')
        );
    }
}

Then you can utilize that trait in your filament page like this. This is for example your resource list page.
use App\Filament\Pages\Concerns\HasHeadingIcon;
use Filament\Support\Enums\IconSize;
use Filament\Support\Enums\IconPosition;

class ListPosts extends ListRecords
{
    use HasHeadingIcon;

    public function getHeading(): string
    {
        return $this->getHeadingWithIcon(
            heading: 'Blog posts',
            icon: 'heroicon-o-document-text',
            iconColor: 'success',
            iconPosition: IconPosition::Before,
            iconSize: IconSize::Medium
        );
    }
}

In this example these params can be modified, but the required is only an icon. The rest are defaults. So you can keep it simple like this:
use App\Filament\Pages\Concerns\HasHeadingIcon;

class ListPosts extends ListRecords
{
    use HasHeadingIcon;

    public function getTitle(): string
    {
        return 'This is a page title';
    }

    public function getHeading(): string
    {
        return $this->getHeadingWithIcon(
            icon: 'heroicon-o-document-text',
        );

        // You can provide page heading text to this function directly
        // like in the previous example. However if you do not provide
        // heading text it will then fallback to value of
        // $heading class property. If that property is also not defined
        // then it will try to get text from getTitle() method.
    }
}

Just to be clear, getTitle() method in Filament is used to define page's title attribute. The attribute is stripped from any HTML code. If getHeading() method is provided then it will be used for page heading text.
